# How to remove "Built with Sphinx using a theme provided by Read the Docs." from RTD theme built docs?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

How can I remove the sentence that's shown underneath each page that's built using RTD theme:

> *"Built with [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) using a [theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme) provided by [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/)."*

[image]

It's my understanding that the RTD theme is released under [MIT license](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/master/LICENSE). My project has one document to group all attributions so I don't want the quoted sentence written under every page. I tried looking at the [RTD theme Configuration](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html) but there doesn't seem to be an option to remove the default attribution from the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Clean method

In your `conf.py`, you can set:

```py
html_show_sphinx = False
```

as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_show_sphinx).

---

### Dirty method

You can also hide the whole footer with CSS:

```py
# conf.py
html_css_files = ["css/custom.css"]
```

and in `custom.css`:

```css
.bottom-of-page {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, it saved me a lot of time. I was about to go down the route of trying to use a custom template to override that part of the default RTD-theme.

Comment: Note that some themes/extensions might require you to credit them (MIT license or similar).

So keep that in mind if you decide to completely hide the footer.